# How to access a pointer member within a structure via pointer structure variable?

Tags: c

edit: Updated code wrt complete context.

I am new to programming. Hence, I am facing some issues.
Below is the similar code snippet I am working on

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct game
{
        int data;
        int *flag;
};

typedef struct game *p_game;

int main()
{
        p_game q = malloc(sizeof(struct game));
        q->data = 1;
        *(q->flag) = 1;
        printf("Data = %d Flag = %d\n",q->data,q->flag);

}
```

I am getting segmentation in the statement *(task->flag) = TRUE. Can anyone suggest, I am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: You don't need `struct` keyword in `typedef struct game * p_game;`.

Comment: Have you allocated any space for task->flag?

Comment: Quite likely, your error is no different than the error `char *flag; *flag = TRUE;`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, yes.. I have allocated space.

Comment: Where do you define `struct game`?  I see a typedef for `game`, but no `struct game` definition.

Comment: @Sanman, you have allocated space for `task` as well as `task->flag` right?

Comment: @Mihir, yes.. I have allocated for both

Comment: @Sanman, then I guess you need to show your complete code otherwise it will be all guess work.

Comment: Your syntax is fine (other than the lack of definition of `struct game`), and the following works: `struct game g; int c; g.flag=&c; toggle(&g);`  I strongly suspect you simply have not properly initialized the flag to be pointing to a writable location.

Answer (score 0):

please share more code.

my guess is that you didn't point the `bool *flag` to anywhere.

you need to have in the code something like this:

```
game a;
bool out_flag=TRUE;

a.flag = &out_flag;
```

or you can just change the struct to be like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int data;
    bool flag;
}game;

typedef struct game * p_game;

BOOL toggle(p_game task)
{
    task->flag = TRUE;

}
```

Comment: Please look into the code something similar I am working on. 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct game
{
        int data;
        int *flag;
};

typedef struct game *p_game;

int main()
{
        p_game q = malloc(sizeof(struct game));
        q->data = 1;
        *(q->flag) = 1; //This is the point, program crashes. I cant alter code, as I am receiving the params from app clients
        printf("Data = %d Flag = %d\n",q->data,q->flag);

}